# How to locally test FastAPI app using AWS JWT authorizer & API Gateway

Tags: python, pytest, aws-api-gateway, fastapi, mangum

I'm struggling to implement testing on my FastAPI which runs under Mangum as a Lambda behind an AWS API Gateway with the [AWS  JWT Authorizer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-jwt-authorizer.html).

> After validating the JWT, API Gateway passes the claims in the token to the API route’s integration. [...] For example, if the JWT includes an identity claim emailID, it's available to a Lambda integration in `$event.requestContext.authorizer.jwt.claims.emailID`

In the route, I can do the following:

```
@app.get("/claims")
async def claims(request: Request):
    event = request.scope["aws.event"]
    claims = event.get("requestContext",{}).get("authorizer",{}).get("jwt",{}).get("claims",{})
    return claims
```

And that works in the API Gateway to return the claims from the JWT.

Now I want to write a test for `/claims` that mocks the claims in the request. I started like this:

```
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient

client = TestClient(app)

def test_claims():
    resp = client.get("/claims")
    assert resp.status_code == 200
```

FastAPI's TestClient uses httpx, but that means the FastAPI specific `request` parameter cannot be passed directly through the client.

I can run `claims` directly:

```
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_claims():
    aws_event = {
                    "requestContext": {"authorizer": {"jwt": {"claims": {"A": "B"}}}}
    }
    resp = await claims(
        Request(
            scope={
                "type": "http",
                "aws.event": aws_event
            },
        )
    )
    assert resp == aws_event["requestContext"]["authorizer"]["jwt"]["claims"]
```

But now it's not even going through FastAPI's router anymore.

I feel like there should be some way to inject scope content into the request I'm making with httpx,  perhaps by wrapping / modifying `fastapi.TestClient`.  But I'm not enough of a pythonista to figure it out.

Comment: hi @erik258  - you would be need to create custom TestClient that takes  an AWS Event along with the app.

Answer (score 1):

One solution I don't love, but works, is to add middleware into my app at test time:

```
testing_claims = { "my": "claims for testing" }

@app.middleware("http")
async def add_claims(request: Request, call_next):
    request.scope["aws.event"] = {"requestContext": {"authorizer": {"jwt": {"claims": testing_claims }}}}
    return await call_next(request)
... 

def test_claims():
    resp = client.get("/claims")
    json = resp.json()
    print(json)
    assert testing_claims == json
```

Comment: The middleware in a "testing context", works. Thanks! Other posibble solution, more complicated, is trying to mock the Scope of the Mangun library...

Comment: It's actually Starlette I think provides that scope.  Mangum handles translating from API Gateway incoming event to Starlette request.